# Tomcat startup script output not available with piping (grep)

Tags: bash, stdout, tomcat

I'm completely puzzled by this behavior of Tomcat 9.0.21 startup script catalina.sh:

```
# following line added by me
echo "CATALINA_HOME"
# following line added by me
echo $have_tty

if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
  # following line added by me
  echo "CATALINA_HOME"

  echo "Using CATALINA_BASE:   $CATALINA_BASE"
  echo "Using CATALINA_HOME:   $CATALINA_HOME"
  echo "Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: $CATALINA_TMPDIR"
  if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
    echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
  else
    echo "Using JRE_HOME:        $JRE_HOME"
  fi
  echo "Using CLASSPATH:       $CLASSPATH"
  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo "Using CATALINA_PID:    $CATALINA_PID"
  fi
fi
```

Now when I run `catalina version | grep CATALINA_HOME` I cannot see any result with the original script version.
In my modified version of script **I can only see what's echo-ed before the 'if have_tty' section!**

```
catalina | grep CATALINA
CATALINA_HOME
```

I'd expect to see also the next CATALINA_HOME echo-ed from within the if block as well as the "Using CATALINA_HOME ..." line.

What's going on there?

(If it matters I'm running Mac OS X 10.14.5 with iTerm and zsh as my shell)

**UPDATE**

People commented that it's because the `have_tty` variable isn't set but that's not a problem in my case.
When I just run `catalina version` I get the full output:

```
CATALINA_HOME
1
CATALINA_HOME
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.21/libexec
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.21/libexec
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.21/libexec/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Users/jumar/.jenv/versions/1.8.0.171
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.21/libexec/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.21/libexec/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.21
...
```

It's just with the pipe (grep) that things start looking weird:

```
catalina version | grep CATALINA_HOME
CATALINA_HOME
# here should be the missing "Using CATALINA_HOME..."
```

Comment: it means that $have_tty is not equal to 1. You'll have to look how it's previously set

Comment: It seems that according to [this test](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.21/bin/catalina.sh#L229) your standard output is not considered to be using a terminal. You have to check out why in your particular context.

Comment: using @Zeitounator's comment, reproducer: `test -t 1; echo $?` versus `(test -t 1; echo $? ) | cat` . Usually the test is done on stdin (eg the tty command), but here it's done on stdout

Comment: Thanks for the comments but have_tty is not a problem. it is set to 1. When I remove the pipe (grep) then I can see everything in the console. It's just with the pipe that the things start going wild. Not sure exactly what it does but `test -t 1; echo $?` returns 0.

Comment: So it seems that using the `catalina` script in the pipe makes the `if [ -t 1 ];` fail and `have_tty` is set to zero in that case. I was puzzled because using plain `catalina` sets `have_tty` properly to 1. Still not sure if that's a standard behavior or not.

Answer (score 2):

First thanks to @Zeitounator and  @A.B for their comments!

After some testing on different tomcat versions and digging deeper I've found, that indeed the issue is in `have_tty` being set to zero.
Using the catalina script in the pipe makes the `if [ -t 1 ];` test fail.

I was puzzled because using plain `catalina` sets `have_tty` properly to 1. 
It was even weirder because it used to work with previous minor tomcat version.
It was in fact introduced in this commit: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/bf894a0e6b5c8f92b122452645e93d63277ad3ab

It seems that the `-t 1` test isn't appropriate when used in a pipe.
Instead, it should be `-t 0` (this is per A.B's comment "Usually the test is done on stdin").

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `| grep CATALINA` from your test command and if you're not getting any output from the line:

```
echo $have_tty
```

Then $have_tty is not set and would then cause execution to not enter the if block.  You would have to trace where $have_tty is getting set originally.

It looks like catalina uses [this command](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37848) to determine if it has a tty:

```
$ tty
/dev/ttys011
```

To get a tty, be sure the script is run from the command line and not through a non-tty process (e.g. init process)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not a problem. have_tty variable is set. When I remove the pipe (grep) then I can see everything in the console. It's just wit the pipe that the things start going wild...

Comment: What does this produce? `catalina | grep '.*'`

Comment: it's similar to the example in my question. Basically it produces the output as just `catalina` BUT the "Using ..." messages aren't present.